# Regularity of measures proof

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, metric-spaces

> A probability measure $\mathbb P$ on a metric space $(S,d)$ is *closed regular* if
>
> $$ \mathbb P(A) = \sup \{ \mathbb P(F) : F \subseteq A, F \text{ - closed} \} \text{*}$$
>
> with $A\in \mathscr A$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open (or closed) sets.

(pretty sure the probability space is $\left( S, \mathscr A, \mathbb P \right) )$

**Thm.** Every probability measure $\mathbb P$ is *closed regular*.

The proof in the notes starts by considering the following set:

$$\mathscr L = \{ A\in \mathscr A : A \text{ and } A^c  \text{ satisfy *} \}$$

This is where I am stuck, it says that to show that each closed set $F \in \mathscr L$, you show that the open set $F^c$ satisfies $\text{*}$ After this the proof is relatively easy to follow I am unsure about this one part. It seems to me that all that has been shown is that if $F$ is closed then its open compliment satisfies the condition, not that either of them are in $\mathscr L$?

Comment: That a closed set satisfies $*$ is obvious by definition. So to show that a given closed set is in $\mathcal L$, it is indeed enough to show that $F^c$ satisfies $*$.

Comment: What is obvious is that if $A$ is a closed set, then the property holds true. What is not obvious is that it holds true for any *Borel* set $A$.

Comment: Maybe I see what causes you some trouble: the same letter $F$ is used for two different things.

Comment: Yes I was just about to type that I have been massively confused by these and only just realised! The sets that need to satisfy * in the definition are the $A\in \mathscr A$. So if a set $A \in \mathscr A$ is closed then * follows immediately since we can have $F=A$ (in *)?